Получение id пользователя при открытии webapp приложения
я хочу сделать кликер в телеграмме, и что бы загрузить прогресс, мне нужно знать id пользователя, который нажал на кнопку открытия webapp. Я пишу бота на java script в телеграмме, используя библиотеку node telegram bot api. Код:
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api')

const TOKEN = 'Тут токен'
const webAppUrl = 'Тут ссылка'

const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN, {
    polling: true
})

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    const chatID = msg.chat.id
    const text = msg.text
    const id = msg.from.id

    if(text === '/start') {
        bot.sendMessage(chatID, `ок\nID: ${id}`, {
            reply_markup: {
                inline_keyboard:[
                    [{text: 'Тут приветственный текст бота', web_app: {url: webAppUrl}}]
                ]
            }
        })
    }
    else {}
})

Вопрос: как мне получить id?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Можно передавать информацию о пользователе прямо в ссылке на WebApp (т.е Query методом), после этого ловить эти данные на сервере и выполнять последующие манипуляции. Пример на Python:
InlineKeyboardButton(text='Приветственный текст', web_app=f'{WebAppUrl}/app?id={id}')


Добрый день. Спасибо большое!
